# Find duplicate and mark as 1st and rest of the dup mark with "Other Dups"

Tags: excel

I have an excel file that I need to make some changes. I need to identify the duplicate and then put "1st" in the series column for the first dup. For the remainder dups need to put "other dups" in the series column. Is it possible? I tried vlookup and match and nothing helped. =vlookup(a1,a2,0) , match(a1,a2,0), or even if(a1=a2,"found match")

[image]

Comment: @torres - typically on this site you're expected to show that you've made at least some attempt to solve a problem yourself.  A question which just asks "is it possible", without showing that you've tried anything at all, is likely (justifiably) to either be closed or just to get the "yes" answer.

Comment: I tried vlookup, match etc. and nothing worked. so I wanted to start fresh and not go with those route. Barry is my good buddy and he helped me without any hussle.

Comment: @torres 1) There is no need to shout. :) 2) If I want, I can downvote your question on 2 accounts. For not providing enough info and for shouting in the comments but I'll let it pass. However, I would recommend reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Sorry. Thanks. I was frustrated as I spent 4 hours to come up with the right formula. Hope you understand.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Is it possible to mark the other dups like columnvalue from c-2, c-3, c-4, etc. so cell d3 will read 84-2, d4 will read 88-3 etc. I tried concatenate but not getting the desired result.

Comment: @torres: Yes it is possible. In fact the formula given by Barry will help you out. See the `"1st","other dups"` part of the formula and understand how it works. Give it a try and if you are still stuck, I will post the formula

Comment: I tried this and not making it serial. =FIND(c3,c2,FIND(c3,c2)+1). Barry's formula is good. I need to another column and concatenate in order the dup was found. so confuse. Let me try what you have suggested

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Sid, I tried work with Barry's formula but is not taking me anywhere. Not proficient in Excel. Can you please give me a hint what I should do. Truly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @torres: Paste this in D2 `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,C2&"-"&1,C2&"-"&COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)),"")` and drag it down. Is this what you are trying?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Sid it worked for the first row of each dup. The remainder rows concatenates columnC-0. so 60-0, 70-0, 85-0

Comment: @torres: I am not sure how are you inputting the formula. It works for me. See the snapshot http://wikisend.com/download/933112/Untitled.jpg

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I must be doing something wrong. Do I need to enable something in Excel? I am using Excel 2010. http://wikisend.com/download/918766/Excel-Serializing.png

Comment: I copied and pasted the formula into notepad and pasted in D2 cell. hmm. I wonder if there is an hidden character. http://wikisend.com/download/888500/Excel-Serializing.png

Comment: @SiddharthRout: You are awesome. I found the issue. I pasted the formula into Notepad++ and there were ?? after the last A2. I took them out and pasted back in the D2 and now it's all fine. Thank you sir very very very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data starts at A2 try this formula in B2 copied down

`=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,"1st","other dups"),"")`

Comment: Is it possible to mark the other dups like columnvalue from c-2, c-3, c-4, etc. so cell d3 will read 84-2, d4 will read 88-3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the **occurrence** instead of '**1st**' and '**other dups**', use the following formula in B2 copied down :

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A;A2)>1;COUNTIF(A$2:A2;A2);1)
```

Example:
[image]

The requirement is that column 'A' is sorted.

Comment: Also useful answer, however, the formula was incorrect. should read =IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2),1)

Comment: Depending on your language/locale settings in Excel, you need to use a ; or a , in a formula.